# How do you check for soft or muddy ground on a backcountry landing?

Tags: landing, pilot-technique, tail-dragger, bush-flying

I've been curious about backcountry landings, but one part of the practice still seems to based more on instinct and experience than on well-explained processes.  I've read about making sure the strip is long enough, looking for power lines, avoiding campers and wildlife, checking your GA area, and other stuff, but **what about mud**?

Everyone seems to say that you do a pass close to the ground or a touch and go, but after that they seem to just make an educated guess based on how the ground looks and feels.  Given that a misjudgement here could be disastrous and prevent you from being able to accelerate to a take off, what's the actual process and list of things to consider to make sure you're landing in a good airstrip and not a foot of deceptive-looking mud?  Does a touch-and-go give you enough information or do you need to carefully consider things like recent rainfall, watershed shape, etc.?

[image: Muddy landing in a tail-dragger on a riverbed]
Image from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtDMHtr93Ys).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, it's a combination of making a couple of low altitude passes over the landing site and visually observing the conditions of the terrain in the area and personal experience selecting a site based upon the knowledge of the local terrain and soil, recent weather conditions, local flooding, ground vegetation, etc.  It's a bush pilot skill based partly on intuition as well as instruction from senior airmen with experience flying in the area.